# Boost library static linking on Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, boost, static-linking

I am using the Boost library on OS X using Xcode. Boost was installed on my system using macports. I have successfully built my app by adding the 3 boost libraries I need (for example, libboost_thread-mt.a) to that Targets 'Link Binary With Libraries' list. However I need to link these libraries statically so that the app will run on other computers without the boost library needing to be installed.

How do I do this exactly? Through my numerous google searches I'm finding I might need to add '-static' - where do I add this in Xcode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've linked with a `.a` library, then you have already linked statically. You never need to ship `.a` libraries. They're just bundles of objects.

---

**EDIT:** Your error strongly suggests that you're linking the dylib rather than the .a. If you have `libfoo.dylib` and `libfoo.a` in your library path, even if you say "link `libfoo.a`" in Xcode, and even if `libfoo.a` is earlier in the search path, it will still link `libfoo.dylib`. This is because Xcode's linking is totally broken and passes `-lfoo` to the linker (you should never use `-l` for something you built and have the exact path to). I always recommend linking libraries you built in `LDFLAGS` in an xcconfig file rather than using the build pane. You pass the exact path you want rather than using `-l`. See [Abandoning the Build Panel](http://robnapier.net/blog/build-system-1-build-panel-360) for more of my thoughts on xcconfig. It's out of date now, since it was written for Xcode3, but the basics still apply.

Using the build pane, you can also pass the entire path to the library in "Other Linker Flags." But this still has all the problems of the build pane.

The quicker (but less robust) solution is sometimes to add `-Wl,-search_paths_first` to the "Other Linker Flags." This changes the behavior so that each library path is searched for both `.dylib` and `.a` before going on (the default behavior is to search everywhere for `.dylib` and only then search for `.a`). So if your `.a` is in a different directory from your `.dylib`, and that directory is earlier in the search path, this will work.

This question finally got me to open a [radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1580401) on this, which I should have done years ago. I recommend that others open [duplicates](http://blackpixel.com/blog/1558/radar-or-gtfo/).

Comment: That's what I thought though when trying to run the app on a different computer the app won't run and comes up with an error saying that it can't locate the relevant .dylib file. Should the .a files be linked to the project somewhere else other than within the 'Link Binary With Libraries' section?

Comment: "Using the build pane, you can also pass the entire path to the library in "Other Linker Flags." - this solved the problem. Thanks!