# making an installable executable for os x

Tags: c++, macos, g++, clang++

I have an application that both compiles with the clang++ and the g++ version 4.7 on OS X. The application I wrote uses third party sdks such as opencv, glfw, etc to name a few. As of now I can make an executable but it will only run on my own computer because of dependencies. What tools to OS X developers use to export their applications (ie make them installable or executables with all the libraries included)? One more constraint, My current OS is mountain lion but I would like this to be backwards compatible to at least 10.6 or 10.5 which ever was the x64 switch.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to distribute your app as an [application bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_bundle), or just as an executable binary file?

If it's an application bundle, and you can acquire and link to your third party SDKs as frameworks (e.g. OpenCV.framework) then you can distribute the frameworks with your app by copying them into the `AppName.app/Contents/Frameworks/` folder.

If it's not an application bundle, or you can't acquire your third party SDKs as frameworks, then you'll need to statically link to those SDKs. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586991/boost-library-static-linking-on-xcode-4) for more info on how to do that.

To build for earlier versions of OS X, set the `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` environment variable before building your program. For example:

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6
```

Comment: I'd recommend him to go with a bundle, it's what almost everyone does nowadays on OSX.

Comment: So I am not using any of the xcode tool chain as of now. I'm going to look into how this bundle thing works. thanks for the info

Comment: @user1881587 It is fairly straightforward to create an app bundle outside of Xcode. You can look in other apps installed on your system to see the layout of the bundle. The main thing you need to do is create an `Info.plist` file and populate it with the right values for your app.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, learn how to make a bundle, it will save you a lot of pain. Secondly, you *should* be able to compile for older version of OSX, but in practice it can be very hard to make it work. It's best to keep an older installation around.